# Muledosft: Delete file in exception flow

Tags: mule

I have flow which works with file. If it is successful then file is deleted automatically in the end of the flow.

If exception occurs I copy file to the error folder but this File connector cannot delete original file (by setting Connector Configuration Auto Delete check box) because it is still handled in the main flow which produced the exception.

What would be Mule's way to delete original file and prevent main flow to go forever?

Answer (score 0):

In the main flow, save original payload and original file name in some variables in the beginning of the flow only. In case of error, fetch the original payload and original filename and write it in the same directory using File connector.

Comment: Sounds good for simple cases, But simple case will not have such challenge. File will be consumed on the beginning of the flow and exception later will not be affected. My question about streams when main flow is still holding the file. Main flow is working as pipe and exception occurs in the middle of the stream.
Yes, I can go inside Java, get the stream and close it. However I thought that maybe Mulesoft had more general common solution.